# Running command in background using cygwin from Windows cmd

Tags: windows, command-line, cygwin

I use cygwin from my Windows command line, I've always done everything quite happily except being able to run something in the background (i.e. putting `&` at the end of a command).

Just to give you more context, I want to be able to start a Mercurial web server and still be able to keep using the command line window and even closing it without killing the server. For example:

```
>hg serve &
listening at http://localhost:8000/ (bound to *:8000)
>echo "Still able to do this"
```

Any workarounds to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
start <command> /B
```

`start` is a windows command, do a `help start` for more info

Alternatively and for my case

```
hg serve --daemon
```

or

```
hg serve -d
```

will do the trick

Comment: For me, `start` is not accessible from cygwin; `cygstart` works though.

Comment: Does not have the desired effect when running from a batch script. The terminal just stays there

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar problem running Apache, finally I used `cygstart`, it's like CMD `start`:

`cygstart --hide /c/apache/bin/httpd.exe`

In this case, it will run Apache as an background proccess thanks to the `--hide` option

Comment: `cygstart` [command line options](http://www.polarhome.com/service/man/?qf=CYGSTART&tf=2&of=Cygwin&sf=1).

Comment: Best answer, works when called from a batch script.