# Using cygwin to netively execute cmd command and redirect stdout

Tags: cmd, cygwin

Using cygwin on Windows 7, need to:

- execute a command in `cmd`
- return immediately (using `START`)
- redirect stdout to a file

I've tried (executed in cygwin):

```
cmd /C "START cmd /C \"executableFileName -f -n 100 > logFilePath.txt\""
```

And many variations of the above line, but nothing worked.

Comment: What happens if you just run `executableFileName -f -n 100 > logFilePath.txt` in Cygwin, does that work?

Comment: The line `executableFileName -f -n 100 > logFilePath.txt &` works, but a bad phenomena happens because of cygwin. When executing natively, it doesn't happen.

Comment: Bummer, that's indeed what I was working towards :(

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158158/running-command-in-background-using-cygwin-from-windows-cmd), using cygstart might be an easier solution.

Comment: @fvu thanks but it needs to run in `cmd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have cygwin, so I cannot test. But try the following.

```
cmd /c start cmd /c "executableFileName -f -n 100 >logFilePath.txt"
```

The quotes around the command following `/c` are not required, so you don't need them in the first `cmd /c`. They are useful in the second `cmd /c` to prevent the redirection from activating until the final cmd is executed.

Regarding your original code - the escape character for cmd.exe is `^`, not `\`, and you cannot escape a quote once quoting has begun. That is why I opted not to include any quotes in the outer most `cmd /c`

Comment: It works! Don't understand how, but I think that I've tried something like this and it didn't work... anyway thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you really need `cmd` to run the command, I think the best you can do is:

```bash
powershell -c 'cmd /c "executableFileName -f -n 100 > logFilePath.txt"'
```

When calling Windows programs, cygwin translates `/C` to `C:\` (like `start /b program` --> `start B:\ program`). This messes things up.

Since powershell accepts `-c` instead of `/c`, it works. Inside its command, you can use `/c` safely.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following:

- `start 'executableFileName -f -n 100 > logFilePath.txt'`
- `cmd //c 'executableFileName -f -n 100 > logFilePath.txt'`

Cygwin comes with a very interesting `/usr/bin/start` script, which basically calls `cmd /c start [args]` for you.

I found out that `//c` becomes `/c` when calling a native Windows program. Take a look at the difference:

```
user@pc:~ $ cmd //c echo /c //c
C:/ /c
```